# Автоматическое открытие intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

При открытии видео файла из приложения внешней программой (и большинства других файлов) появляется диалоговое окно со списком программ, в которых можно открыть данный файл. Там же можно поставить галочку, чтобы постоянно открывать файлы данного типа в этой программе.

А как в коде установить программу по умолчанию?

Чтобы видео сразу проигрывалось в стандартном плеере, без появления этого диалогового окна?

Answer (score 2):

Вызвать явный `Intent` для `Activity` стандартного плеера.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно выставить тип для интент, указав приложение, один или несколько. Пример для mxplayer

```
intent.setType("application/com.mxtech.videoplayer.pro|application/com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
```

типы разделять "|" и выставлять по приоритету, если приложение videoplayer.pro не найдено - откроется с помощью videoplayer.ad